# problem with scp: cannot open shared object file

Tags: shared-library, scp

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. When I use `scp` command, I get this error:

```
scp: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory lost connection
```

By googling, I found that this problem may be due to lack of 32-bit version of libraries. I tried all the solutions I found, but the problem hasn't been solved yet. I have checked that I have 32-bit version of `libz.so.1` using `find` command:

```
$ sudo find / | grep libz.so.1   
[sudo] password for javad:  
/usr/lib64/libz.so.1  
/usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.8  
/usr/lib32/libz.so.1  
/usr/lib32/libz.so.1.2.8  
/usr/local/arm/linux-devkit/sysroots/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-linux-gnueabi/lib/libz.so.1  
/usr/local/arm/linux-devkit/sysroots/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-linux-gnueabi/lib/libz.so.1.2.8  
/usr/local/arm/linux-devkit/sysroots/x86_64-arago-linux/usr/lib/libz.so.1  
/usr/local/arm/linux-devkit/sysroots/x86_64-arago-linux/usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8  
/lib64/libz.so.1  
/lib64/libz.so.1.2.8  
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1    
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8  
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1  
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8  
/lib32/libz.so.1  
/lib32/libz.so.1.2.8
```

It seems that I have 32-bit version of this library.

I checked dependency of scp too:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/scp  
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcf19ed000)  
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f768e42e000)  
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000556c52736000)
```

Could anyone help me find the problem, please?

Comment: Are you sure the command is locating the correct executable? what does `type scp` say?

Comment: yes, i think it is. output of type scp is: "scp is hashed (/usr/bin/scp)"